# Problems when run Dusk Laravel 5.4 Ubuntu

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I followed the tutorial from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk but when I run `php artisan dusk`

[image]

Freeze on it and not execute nothing more, also not open any browser. Someone have some Idea why ?

Bellow you can see my AppServiceProvider:

[image: AppServiceProvider]

Then if take so long it's showing this:
[image]

Comment: There was a problem in Dusk for Ubuntu users but it's fixed see the [PL](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/pull/33) and this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/10)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It's necessary run the chromedrive-linux in a separated terminal before run `php artisan dusk` or integrate with Travis CI or CircleCI which will integrate everything and running together.